# Any changes to Win7 Network Settings produces 3 min of no connectivity

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a Win7 PC that is my main PC on my home lan.

It has a static IP address 192.168.0.10 with a gateway at 192.168.0.1

Now when I boot-up, reboot,resume from sleep or change a network setting I get approx 3mins of no network connectivity.

So, lets say my PC is stable and I want to route my gateway to another PC which connects to my backup ADSL line. On another PC if I change the gateway via network properties or using

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
```

As soon as it's change then I get full network connectivity but on my main Win7 PC nothing happens for 3mins then I do get connectivity. Now both PC are the same Win7 etc.

If I make the change and then do a ping from a cmd window then the ping does nothing and sits then (not even timing out) for 3 mins and then when the interface become available the ping then does it ping 4 times.

During this loss of connectivity I check the routing via ROUTE PRINT and the routes are show that the change has happened, if I do an IPCONFIG it show the changes there as well. I thought it was a gateway issue but I still get no connectivity even if I change IP address from 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.20 which should be near instantaneous but no it makes the change (as it shows up in IPCONFIG/ROUTE etc) and then take 3 mins to make the connection and provide connectivity.

It must be having an issue somewhere and something is obviously waiting for a timeout of 3 mins before the interface come up with connectivity.

I have check the system logs but nothing showing in there.

I have enven run a Network Monitor (Microsoft 3.4) and it shows that connectivity is there before the change, then as I make a change then the network monitor does not show any traffic for 3 mins then it starts showing traffic.

Can anyone share some light on the subject as it is really anoying me now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is often observed the network driver is the reason behind this issue. When you make the changes, you can see them taken place, but eventually its taking time for the settings to update in the system.

Consider removing any unwanted driver if installed.

Remove and re-install network drivers and try again

Hope it works

Comment: I had a Driver Update day yesterday and put a new version of the nForce drivers. Nothing improved. I have done quite a bit more testing and I think I have narrowed it down to DNS issues.

Comment: When I was pinging etc I was pinging hostnames before. So now when I ping IP this shows network connectivity as I get responses back but trying to ping a hostname just freezes during these 3mins. Even if I ping an entry in my HOSTS file I do not get anything for these 3mins. I changed my DNS lookup from OpenDNS to Googles, reboot but still the same issue. I have now installed a DNS server on my Server and still no lookups for these 3mins. So it must be something on my PC that is interferring with the DNS. I have tried flushing the DNS etc.

Comment: What I do not understand is that why even an entry in the HOSTS file is not being resolved for 3mins. So what would stop DNS reading the HOSTS file. I think it is this point that is causung my problem as if it can not get a local lookup then it will just freeze and timeout before doing a DNS requst off a server